# Rewrite sub domain to main domain using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a url something like

www.mydomain.com/mydomain

but when someone types as www.mydomain.com the above should load without url redirection. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.yourdomain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdomain/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Also see : [Apache mod_rewrite - rewriting from subdomain to main domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826945/apache-mod-rewrite-rewriting-from-subdomain-to-main-domain)